# One specific font not displaying accented characters on my Wordpress blog

Tags: css, wordpress, encoding, fonts

I'm setting up a new Wordpress blog, and I want to use "Spantaran" font for titles.

The problem is, this is the only font that doesn't want to display accented characters: they're just replaced with blanks.

It's working fine with other fonts.

Just using this in CSS:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6 {
vertical-align: baseline;
display: block;
color: #333;
font-weight: 400;
font-family: "Spantaran", sans-serif;
}
```

If I put anything else than "Spantaran", it will work correctly.
I do have "UFT-8" in my HTML header, and this in my wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

I've downloaded the fonts files to my theme's "fonts" folder just in case, but I don't know how to force my site to call them instead of the built-in version.

What can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the `@font-face` rule in your CSS, by any chance? (And if not, @font-face, how are you including the Spantaran file?

Comment: Maybe Spantaran is incomplete and just don't have the glyphs for accented characters. Open it on charmap and check

Answer (score 0):

Seems indeed the problem I'm having is related to the font itself, since even on Windows, when I type in these characters, they don't appear.

Thanks.